# Compilation when Column doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've a Stored procedure which looks like this:

```
create procedure test as
begin
if  exists(
               select 1 from sys.columns 
                where Name      = N'Column2'
                  and Object_ID = Object_ID(Table2')
              )

select Column2 from Table2
end
```

I want to run this procedure on db where **Column2 doesn't exist**. I don't want to take existence check out of SP. Currently the error is :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line
>   39 [Batch Start Line 0] Invalid column name 'Column2'.

Is there any way to do so? Why yes and why not?

and why for instance if you check for existence table and select non-existent table that works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
create procedure test as
begin
    if exists (select 1
               from sys.columns 
               where Name = N'Column2' and Object_ID = Object_ID('Table2')
              )
    begin
        exec sp_executesql N'select Column2 from Table2';
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I never knew this is possible

Comment: Very interesting. Does anybody knows why existence check works fro tables and not for columns?

Comment: @Sher It was an arbitrary decision - if you want factual reasons behind it, you'd have to interview members of the late 1990s/early 2000s Sybase/SQL Server team.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, It shouldn't be arbitrary decision. Something must be different, maybe column object is kind of different type.

Comment: @Sher They made a lot of arbitrary decisions back then - `timestamp` (a confusing type name that also violates ANSI), NULL handling (unique constraints treat two NULLs as "equal" - also violating ANSI), etc. I'm not saying it *should* have been an arbitrary decision, just that deferred name resolution allows you to reference a table that doesn't exist, but not a column, and that was a decision made ages ago that I can only characterize as arbitrary. And yes, a column is a different type of entity than a table.